# Element-Wise Filtering of Jagged Multidimensional Array with 1D array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements

```js
const Amaths = [
    [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [4, 5, 6, 8],
    [12, 3, 4]
]
const checks = [2.5, 4.01, 5];
const picks = [];
for (let j = 0; j < Amaths.length; j++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < Amaths[j].length; k++) {
        if (Amaths[j][k] > checks[j]) {
            picks.push(Amaths[j][k]);
        }
    }
}

console.log("picks", picks)
```

I want to filter a jagged multidimensional array element-wis without flattening the output array; in this example, "picks".

I have tried using a for loop but the output, "picks", is flattened. Also, I have used mathjs library function, but it seems the element-wise arithmetic operations in this library only works for non-jagged multidimensional arrays.

The expected result should be:

```js
const picks =  [ [3, 5, 6, 7, 8], [5, 6, 8], [12] ]

console.log ("expected picks", picks)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.map` to transform into another 2d array, calling `.filter` on each subarray while comparing against the `checks` at the index of the subarray being iterated over:

```js
const Amaths = [
    [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [4, 5, 6, 8],
    [12, 3, 4]
]
const checks = [2.5, 4.01, 5];

const result = Amaths.map(
  (subarr, i) => subarr.filter(
    num => num >= checks[i]
  )
);
console.log(result);
```

To fix your original code, you'd have to push a new subarray to `picks` on every outer iteration:

```js
const Amaths = [
    [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [4, 5, 6, 8],
    [12, 3, 4]
]
const checks = [2.5, 4.01, 5];
const picks = [];
for (let j = 0; j < Amaths.length; j++) {
    picks.push([]);
    for (let k = 0; k < Amaths[j].length; k++) {
        if (Amaths[j][k] > checks[j]) {
            picks[j].push(Amaths[j][k]);
        }
    }
}

console.log("picks", picks)
```

(but array methods are probably a much better choice here, they're a lot more concise and easy to understand)